# Spell checking a .md file in GitHub while accessing the online .md editor

Tags: chrome, github, spell-checker

Is there an easy way to spell check markdown files in GitHub while editing them directly online using the Chrome browser? I tried a few Chrome plugins but they don't seem to recognize the markdown editor area as a valid area to apply spell checks. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I also had trouble finding a tool/extension that would work. The best option I could find was the chrome extension below. You have to switch the markdown to preview mode, highlight and right click the word you want to spell check, and select the "spell check" option in the dropdown menu. It's not very practical but it's the closest thing I could find for spell checking Github/GitLab's inline text editor.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spell-checker-for-chrome/jfpdnkkdgghlpdgldicfgnnnkhdfhocg/related?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Grammarly, which has a fantastic browser extension. It checks all your grammar and spelling as you work. You get to choose what to accept, but it is often correct. Go to https://grammarly.com for more information. They have a free membership level.

Disclaimer: I do not work for nor benefit from my endorsement of Grammarly.

Note: I used Grammarly to edit this text.